# Перенести коммит в более раннее состояние той же ветки

Tags: git

a-b-c-d-e, где d - нужный коммит, изменяющий 3 строки. 
Появилась необходимость, чтобы стало так: d-a-b-c-e, конфликтов, связанных с изменениями, нет.  
Главное - как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужен [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) или [interactive rebase](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141160/). Этому посвящена целая глава в книге (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), только я ее не читал, поэтому точнее ничего не скажу.

Answer (score 7):

Вам нужен `git rebase -i HEAD~5`. Эта команда запустит интерактивный `reabse` последних 5 коммитов, в ходе которого вы сможете в том числе менять порядок их следования. После запуска этой команды появится текстовый редактор (если вы не настраивали редактор по умолчанию, то открется vim), где каждому коммиту будет соответствовать строчка формата

```
action hash comment
```

В вашем случае нужно поменять местами строки. В vim это делается так: наводится курсор на строку, `Shift+D`, переводится курсор под строку, куда нужно вставить, `Shift+P`. Если что-то вставилось неправильно, жмём `i` (это переведёт нас в привычный режим редактирования) и исправляем, после чего жмём `Esc`. Затем нужно сохраниться и выйти. Для этого печатаем `:wq` и жмём `Enter`. Если передумали или накосячили с редактированием, печатаем `:q!` и выходим без сохранения. После этого `git` поменяет коммиты местами в том порядке, в каком они были перечислены в отредактированном файле.

Вообще, интерактивный `rebase` умеет много чего интересного. В частности, можно переименовать коммит, удалить его, слить несколько коммитов в один. Читайте [документацию](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8), и будет вам счастье.